# Overlapping buttons in Xamarin.Forms grid

Tags: xaml, button, xamarin.forms, grid, piano

I'm trying to develop a Xamarin.Forms application.

I have the following grid, displayed like a piano keyboard:

[image]

and, for example, this code, in xaml:

```
   <Grid ColumnSpacing="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="120" />
          <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="0"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="C"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="1"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="D"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="2"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="E"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="3"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="F"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="4"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="G"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="5"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="A"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />
        <Button
          Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Grid.Column="6"
          BackgroundColor="White"
          Text="B"
          TextColor="Black"
          WidthRequest="45" />

        <Button
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          BackgroundColor="Black"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="C#"
          TextColor="White"
          WidthRequest="35" />
        <Button
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          BackgroundColor="Black"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="D#"
          TextColor="White"
          WidthRequest="35" />
        <Button
          Grid.Column="3"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          BackgroundColor="Black"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="F#"
          TextColor="White"
          WidthRequest="35" />
        <Button
          Grid.Column="4"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          BackgroundColor="Black"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="G#"
          TextColor="White"
          WidthRequest="35" />
        <Button
          Grid.Column="5"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          BackgroundColor="Black"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="A#"
          TextColor="White"
          WidthRequest="35" />
      </Grid>
```

My issue is that when I click a white button (e.g. "A" button), this happens:

[image]

Do you happen to know how I can fix the position of the buttons, in order to avoid this overlapping?

I'm not sure if the grid is the best way to achieve what I want to display, but I assumed it would be a good choice. If you have a better container for this, please let me know.

Comment: I would try a Label or BoxView with a gesture recognizer instead of a Button

Comment: The symptom you see is Button redrawing itself. Unfortunately, the drawing-order of Grid's children isn't preserved when this happens. That is, grid isn't "smart enough" to know that any overlapping children should also be redrawn. Jason's suggestion avoids that, by "simulating" a button, but without Button's re-draw behavior.